# How can I get a definitive list of the javascript dependencies for jupyterlab

Tags: javascript, python, jupyter-notebook, yarnpkg, jupyter-lab

I am trying to get a list of all the dependencies that get packaged up with jupyterlab v1.1.4. I think that I can get the python dependencies by

```
python3 -m venv .env
pip install jupyterlab==1.1.4
pip freeze
```

But I don't know how to do this for the javascript dependencies. I don't know much about js.

It seems like this information might be in one of the yarn.lock files. But I'm not sure if I want the yarn.lock file in the home directory or the one in /jupyterlab/staging/. The reason I thought it might be the staging one, which is much shorter, is because the [CONTRIBUTING.md](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#notes) says:

> By default, the application will load from the JupyterLab staging directory (default is `<sys-prefix>/share/jupyter/lab/build`. If you wish to run the core application in `<git root>/jupyterlab/build`, run `jupyter lab --core-mode`. This is the core application that will be shipped.

But then the problem is, once I've identified the correct yarn.lock file, how do I remove the dev dependencies? I see that inside [/jupyterlab/staging/package.json](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/blob/v1.1.4/jupyterlab/staging/package.json#L59) there is a section for dev dependencies and that these seem to be included in the yarn.lock file. Everything in the dependencies section of the package.json is prefixed with `@jupyterlab`. Does that mean I can filter the yarn.lock to only keep the blocks that are in this section? So I would keep all of these dependencies

```
"@jupyterlab/coreutils@^3.1.0", "@jupyterlab/coreutils@~3.1.0":
  version "3.1.0"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@jupyterlab/coreutils/-/coreutils-3.1.0.tgz#b307569462c468d6a09dfa06f32fed03e55dd811"
  integrity sha512-ZqgzDUyanyvc86gtCrIbc1M6iniKHYmWNWHvWOcnq3KIP3wk3grchsTYPTfQDxcUS6F04baPGp/KohEU2ml40Q==
  dependencies:
    "@phosphor/commands" "^1.6.3"
    "@phosphor/coreutils" "^1.3.1"
    "@phosphor/disposable" "^1.2.0"
    "@phosphor/properties" "^1.1.3"
    "@phosphor/signaling" "^1.2.3"
    ajv "^6.5.5"
    json5 "^2.1.0"
    minimist "~1.2.0"
    moment "^2.24.0"
    path-posix "~1.0.0"
    url-parse "~1.4.3"
```

because (@jupyterlab/coreutils)[https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/blob/v1.1.4/jupyterlab/staging/package.json#L24] is in the dependencies section, but I can exclude

```
glob@^7.1.3, glob@^7.1.4, glob@~7.1.2:
  version "7.1.4"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/glob/-/glob-7.1.4.tgz#aa608a2f6c577ad357e1ae5a5c26d9a8d1969255"
  integrity sha512-hkLPepehmnKk41pUGm3sYxoFs/umurYfYJCerbXEyFIWcAzvpipAgVkBqqT9RBKMGjnq6kMuyYwha6csxbiM1A==
  dependencies:
    fs.realpath "^1.0.0"
    inflight "^1.0.4"
    inherits "2"
    minimatch "^3.0.4"
    once "^1.3.0"
    path-is-absolute "^1.0.0"
```

because glob is only in the dev dependencies? But what happens if glob is a dependency of one of the non-dev dependencies? In that case I would still want to keep glob and all iot's dependencies.

Finally, does the [resolutions](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/) section imply that I might need to consider more than one version of the same library as being a final dependency that gets packaged up?

Is their some filter for `yarn list` that will maybe give me the list I'm after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yarn list --prod` will only give you the production dependencies that JupyterLab ships with. The `resolutions` section actually *overrides* the package versions- it's used to ensure only one version of the given package is installed. The Yarn utilities for listing dependencies will understand this, so as long as you're going through Yarn you don't have to worry about it.

Note that JupyterLab ships with many dependencies that might normally be considered dev dependencies- this is because it needs to include Webpack and related tooling on end user machines to support extensions.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know which yarn.lock file is correct? It seems that `yarn list` (or rather `jlpm list` gives me a different list depending on if I'm in the root directory or the staging directory.

Comment: Do you have a link to where the `--prod` flag is explained in the docs btw? I would have expected to see it here: https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/list

Comment: The staging directory in `<python prefix>/share/jupyter/lab` will include any extensions you've installed, whereas `<site packages>/jupyterlab/staging` will be just stock JupyterLab. Unfortunately the `--prod` flag isn't well documented, but you can find a few references to it by poking through github: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/3788

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I'm not sure what you mean by `<python prefix>/share/jupyter/lab` or `<site packages>/jupyterlab/staging`. I can't find those folders inside my virtual env. But if I wanted to analyse the dependencies for CVEs, licenses etc, is `yarn list --prod` in the staging directory of the repo the right list?

Comment: Also, once I've done this and flattened th dependency tree and dropped the duplicates, I'm still left with multiple versions of the same library. For example *safe-buffer@5.1.2*, 
*safe-buffer@~5.1.0*,
*safer-buffer@2.1.2*,
*safer-buffer@>= 2.1.2 < 3*. Does that mean that jupyter gets packaged up with all these different versions? Or if it's just one, how do I figure out which one?

Comment: Ah ok I found `<python prefix>/share/jupyter/lab`, I had installed it in editable mode so it never created these directories! Got them now :)